# Validating a string as UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, utf-8

I need some help validating a string to be UTF-8 encoded in Java.

I am processing some Excel sheets and transforming them into an XML document and when I try to validate that XML document I get a "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8-sequence". I validate it here: http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/. I traced down that and it leads me to this:
The character indicated is this apostrophe `’`, which is different from this apostrophe `'`.

I guess what I'm asking is if there is some kind of class that given a String replaces all the non UTF-8 characters with UTF-8 characters, like this:
`String magicalFunction(String stringToFix);`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the related questions (links on your right)?

Comment: Java strings are UTF-16 - always. The problem may be in how you transform them to UTF-8, so post the code you're using to create the XML document.

Answer (score 2):

That comma-like quote is non-ASCII and the error means that the XML cannot be read as UTF-8.
Then maybe the XML text is in Windows Latin-1, aka Windows-1252.

Check the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
```

If the `encoding` attribute is `UTF-8` or missing (defaults to UTF-8) then the file is wrongly generated.

You can check the encoding with an editor capable of switching encodings, like [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org).

Wrong generating a file, could derive from pure text writing.

One should write with something like:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF.8"));
```

The OutputStreamWriter converts from binary bytes (OutputStream) to a text Writer (java String). For that it uses the giving encoding. This encoding parameter is optional (there is a shorter constructor withut encoding), as at many other spots in Java APIs. Then the platform's default encoding is used. The files then are not cross-platform.

The unfortunately often used convenience classes FileWriter and FileReader even totally miss the encoding parameter. There super classes then use the platform encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the idea of "String encoding", the way Java stores characteres internally is not important as you cannot modify it. The problem here is the way you store them in a file: using String.getBytes("UTF-8") and an OutputStream to write those bytes you'll ensure your file is UTF-8. 
Writer uses always the default enconding of the OS, so you cannot use a FileWriter, for example.
You can find more information in the related questions looking at the right side of this page